# why does $(this) selector work from within my function but works from outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically I'm trying to change background-color of some JQuery added divs of class="cell" into a parent div of class="grid". So the "cell" class isn't defined in the original index.html

so it works when i write the code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clr = "red";
    $('.cell').mouseenter(function() { 
        $(this).css('background-color', clr);
    });
});
```

but it doesn't when i define a function like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function fillCell(clr){
        $(this).css('background-color', clr);
    }

    $('.cell').mouseenter(function() { 
        alert(clr);     //added for test 
        fillCell("red");
    });

});
```

please note that the alert() is triggered when hovering and responds with "red".

Comment: `this` doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: please, what am i missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17514482/400654

Answer (score -1):

`this` only works in the context of any function being passed in as a parameter(anonymous or your defined function). What you could do is just pass `this` as a parameter to the function in your case since you need it to do additional things and it would work the way you want it to.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function fillCell(clr, o){
        $(o).css('background-color', clr);
    }

    $('.cell').mouseenter(function() { 
        alert(clr);     //added for test 
        fillCell("red", this);
    });
});
```

Comment: alright, works now! thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Do this instead.

```
fillCell.call(this, "red");
```

The `mouseEnter` event handler has its context (`this`) set to the element that the event was triggered on. However, by extracting your function definition to the outside of the event handler, you're losing the `this` context. `.call()` lets you override that context. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: I'm sorry about the initial errors. I've learnt not to type answers with my phone again :)

Comment: Thank you very much, looks like your method is the best practice

Comment: @Ozilyo Thanks for accepting as the answer. I'd appreciate an upvote, to counter for the downvote that I received because of the bad formatting I did on my phone :)

Comment: I would love to, but I cant cuz I don't have enough reputation :( sorry.